# Wkhtmltopd how to set full width of pdf page

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

In Laravel 10 I'm using wkhtmltopd library to generate a PDF document.

The problem is when I try generate content in full width of the document, top and sides.

Some reason there is always white border around content.

[image]

This is my html code that I use to generate document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #fd7e14">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org//face/open-sauce-one" type="text/css"/>
<meta name="author" content="name author">
<style media="all">
    html {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding:0 !important;
        border:0 !important;
        outline:0 !important;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding:0 !important;
        border:0 !important;
        outline:0 !important;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
   Test Content
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something wrong with styles?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html looks ok to me, but you also need to set all margins to 0 for the **PDF document** (in addition to the html content). The options for wkhtmltopdf on the command line are as follows:

```
wkhtmltopdf -T 0 -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 <input_url> <output_file>
```

It depends on the wrapper used how to set those options in PHP.

See [the manual](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) for further explanations on all options.